# Advantages of SQL Server 2008 over SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, comparison

What are the key differences between Microsoft's SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008?

Are there any compelling reasons for upgrading (any edition, as I have a customer with multiple editions)? Or is there a website with either a chart or bullet point comparison of the two servers?

Also, is there anything noteworthy in the [Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) editions of either version?

Comment: not constructive..huh?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

- Transparent Data Encryption. The
  ability to encrypt an entire
  database.
- Backup Encryption. Executed at
  backup time to prevent tampering.
- External Key Management. Storing
  Keys separate from the data.
- Auditing. Monitoring of data access.
- Data Compression. Fact Table size
  reduction and improved performance.
- Resource Governor. Restrict users or
  groups from consuming high levels or
  resources.
- Hot Plug CPU. Add CPUs on the fly.
- Performance Studio. Collection of
  performance monitoring tools.
- *Installation improvements. Disk
  images and service pack uninstall
  options.*
- Dynamic Development. New ADO and
  Visual Studio options as well as Dot
  Net 3.
- Entity Data Services. Line Of
  Business (LOB) framework and Entity
  Query Language (eSQL)
- LINQ. Development query language for
  access multiple types of data such
  as SQL and XML.
- Data Synchronizing. Development of
  frequently disconnected
  applications.
- Large UDT. No size restriction on
  UDT.
- Dates and Times. New data types:
  Date, Time, Date Time Offset.
- File Stream. New data type
  VarBinary(Max) FileStream for
  managing binary data.
- Table Value Parameters. The ability
  to pass an entire table to a stored
  procedure.
- Spatial Data. Data type for storing
  Latitude, Longitude, and GPS
  entries.
- Full Text Search. Native Indexes,
  thesaurus as metadata, and backup
  ability.
- SQL Server Integration Service.
  Improved multiprocessor support and
  faster lookups.
- MERGE. TSQL command combining
  Insert, Update, and Delete.
- SQL Server Analysis Server. Stack
  improvements, faster block
  computations.
- SQL Server Reporting Server.
  Improved memory management and
  better rendering.
- Microsoft Office 2007. Use OFFICE as
  an SSRS template. SSRS to WORD.
- SQL 2000 Support Ends. Mainstream Support for SQL 2000 is coming to an end.

(Good intro article [part 1](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3691821), [part 2](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3697056), [part 3](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3702381).
As for compelling reasons, that depends on what you are using SQL server for. Do you need [hierarchical data types](http://blogs.msdn.com/manisblog/archive/2007/08/17/sql-server-2008-hierarchyid.aspx)? Do you currently store files in the database and want to switch over to [SQL Server's new filestream feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/rdoherty/archive/2007/10/12/getting-traction-with-sql-server-2008-filestream.aspx)? Could you use more disk space by turning on [data compression](http://blogs.msdn.com/chadboyd/archive/2007/07/28/katmai-sql-2008-data-compression-including-backup-compression.aspx)?

And let's not forget the ability to [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx) data.

Comment: Remember that some of the features are only supported by Enterprice (and Developer) edition. see http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx

Answer (score 13):

Be aware that a lot of the really killer features are only in Enterprise Edition.  Data compression and backup compression are among two of my top favorites - they give you free performance improvements right off the bat.  Data compression lessens the amount of I/O you have to do, so a lot of queries speed up 20-40%.  CPU use goes up, but in today's multi-core environments, we often have more CPU power but not more IO.  Anyway, those are only in Enterprise.

If you're only going to use Standard Edition, then most of the improvements require changes to your application code and T-SQL code, so it's not quite as easy of a sell.

Comment: Quest Software is annoying. They ask for first, lastname & email. Submit. Then they ask for address, phone number.. A white paper made to capture more "potential" customers. I didn't bother to fill out the info!

Comment: Gosh, people that want to feed themselves in exchange for providing information? It's unthinkable!

Answer (score 5):

Someone with more reputation can copy this into the main answer:

- Change Tracking. Allows you to get info on what changes happened to which rows since a specific version.
- Change Data Capture. Allows all changes to be captured and queried. (Enterprise)

Answer (score 5):

I guess it depends on your role

For me as a developer:

- Merge statement
- Reporting Services improvement
- Date/time changes

Edit, *late* update, after using it

- filtered indexes
- table valued parameters
- Reporting Services without IIS

Answer (score 5):

I went to a bunch of SQL Server 2008 talks in [PASS 2008](http://summit2008.sqlpass.org/), the only 'killer feature' from my point of view is extended events.

There are lots of great improvements, but that was the only one that got close to being a game changer for me. Table value parameters and merge were probably my next favourite. Day-to-day, [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) is a huge win.. But this isn't really specific to SQL Server 2008, just the SQL Server 2008 toolset (other tools can give you similar IntelliSense against SQL Server 2005, 2000, etc.).

Comment: Could you explain extended events?

Comment: Extended events give you a lot more power in collecting info for debugging. You can choose guaranteed delivery (like profiler does) or 'best attempt', this is nice in case you have to debug something in production. There is a decent overview on Technet - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd314391.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There are new [features added](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/overview.aspx). But, you will have to see if it is worth the upgrade. Some good [improvements in Management Studio 2008](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/management-studio-improvements-in-sql-server-2008/) though, especially the intellisense for the Query Editor.

Answer (score 4):

SQL 2008 also allows you to disable lock escalation on specific tables. I have found this very useful on small frequently updated tables where locks can escalate causing concurrency issues. In SQL 2005, even with the ROWLOCK hint on delete statements locks can be escalated which can lead to deadlocks. In my testing, an application which I have developed had concurrency issues during small table manipulation due to lock escalation on SQL 2005. In SQL  2008 this problem went away.

It is still important to bear in mind the potential overhead of handling large numbers of row locks, but having the option to stop escalation when you want to is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

One of my favourites are Filtered indexes. Now I can create lightning fast covering indexes for my most critical queries with only minor impact on DML statements.

/Håkan Winther

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2008 introduces four new date and time data types, which include:

```
* DATE: As you can imagine, the DATE data type only stores a date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD. It has a range of 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-32, which should be adequate for most business and scientific applications. The accuracy is 1 day, and it only takes 3 bytes to store the date.
* TIME: TIME is stored in the format: hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn, with a range of 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59:9999999 and is accurate to 100 nanoseconds. Storage depends on the precision and scale selected, and runs from 3 to 5 bytes.
* DATETIME2: DATETIME2 is very similar to the older DATETIME data type, but has a greater range and precision. The format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:nnnnnnnm with a range of 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 through 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999, and an accuracy of 100 nanoseconds. Storage depends on the precision and scale selected, and runs from 6 to 8 bytes.
* DATETIMEOFFSET: DATETIMEOFFSET is similar to DATETIME2, but includes additional information to track the time zone. The format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] [+|-]hh:mm with a range of 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 through 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 through 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 (in UTC), and an accuracy of 100 nanoseconds. Storage depends on the precision and scale selected, and runs from 8 to 10 bytes.
```

http://soft-engineering.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

The new features are really great and its meets the very important factors of current age. For .net people it’s always be a boon to use SQL Server, I hope using the latest version we will have **better security** and better performance as well as the introduction of **compression** the size of the database. The **backup encryption** utility is also phenomenon.

Once again thanks to Microsoft for their great thoughts in form of software :)

Answer (score 2):

The Denver SQL Server Users group has had some really good presentations over the last couple of months on the new features in SQL 2008 including one from Paul Nielsen just last week shortly after he got back from "Jump Start" up in Redmond (if I remember the name of the event correctly).

A couple of caveats on all of the "new features" for SQL 2008, the triage to determine which features will be in the various editions is still in progress. Many/most of the new/very cool features like data compression, partitioned indexes, policies, etc. are only going to be in the enterprise edition. Unless you're planning on running enterprise edition a lot of the features that are in the CTP's will probably not be in SQL 2008 standard, etc.

On other minor but often overlooked issue - SQL 2008 will only be 64-bit, if you're buying new hardware shouldn't be an issue but if you're planning on using existing hardware... also, if you've got dependencies on third party drivers (e.g. oracle) best be sure that a 64-bit version is available/works

Comment: Just a note... I have installed SQL 2008 R2 on several 32-bit systems.