# What are the major differences between Sql Server 2005 and Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advantages of SQL Server 2008 over SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198478/advantages-of-sql-server-2008-over-sql-server-2005)

What are the major differences between Sql Server 2005 and Sql Server 2008?

How could I convince my organization to invest in Sql Server 2008?

For me, one major aspect that I see is that they have a good framework to programmatically generate SSIS packages with the use of ezAPI.

I want to know your reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: I think, you will have to convince yourself first for the reasons to use SQL 2008. Are there any reasons for yourself to do it?

Comment: Unless you can qualify you motivations, i.e. what type of application platform you working with etc. then I suspect this thread may get closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's new in SQL Server 2008

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/whats-new.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This might help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.04.overview.aspx?pr=blog

It covers new features of SQL Server 2008 from the perspective of management, developers and a few other aspects.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 allows for table valued parameters.  These eliminate the need for red sqling in statements.  I am by no means a dba, but from my programmer background perspective this feature can't be beat.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Reporting Services in SQL Server 2008 supports native export to Word Documents.  This is a pretty big feature.... For example, 2005 supported PDF, but if you wanted to change anything on the report, PDF is not the way to go.