# Which Express Edition to go with: SQL Server 2005 or 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

For migrating my old database from MySQL to SQL Server, which edition is suitable, 2005 or 2008 R2? Some developers suggested me to stick to the old version.

Suggest Pros and Cons. I will be using with my .NET standalone Windows app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend 2008 R2 over the 2005 Express Edition for the fact that the database size limit on 2005 Express is 4 GB, when 2008 bumped that up to 10 GB.  RAM is still [limited to a maximum of 1 GB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

There's also the addition of the [hierarchyid](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119182550/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/manisblog/archive/2007/08/17/sql-server-2008-hierarchyid.aspx), besides the fact of impending loss of support for 2005...

Comment: +1 for bringing up the increased gb limit.  I didn't know they bumped it up in 2008.  That makes me so happy that I may just track down a couple other comments of yours and upvote them as well.

Comment: @vgv8: the rest of the sentence (answer, really) explains why.

Comment: Is there any limitation on RAM? Is it still 2GB?

Comment: @RPK: Both [2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345154%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and 2008 are limited to a max of 1 GB

Comment: @OMG: Than not of any use. My customer's PC has 2GB RAM.

Comment: @RPK: That's about what you can expect from the various Express versions - Oracle, DB2, etc.  PostgreSQL might be worth considering.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with 2008 R2, if for no other reason then the fact that [mainstream support for 2005 will end on 04/12/2011](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=SQL).

Answer (score 1):

https://serverfault.com/questions/121299/migrate-sql-server-2000-which-is-better-2005-vs-2008

[Advantages of SQL Server 2008 over SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198478/advantages-of-ms-sql-server-2008-over-ms-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has announced that mainstream support for SQL Server 2005 will end 4/12/2001. http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle

I would use the newer version as it has a longer life span and also has some cool features like the compressed storage format and compressed backups.  If you are thinking of using the free Express version 2008 R2 allows databases of up to 10GB, while the older version limits you to 4GB.

Comment: But the RAM limit is still 1 GB I guess. My customer's PC has 2 GB RAM.

Comment: That is 1 GB completely dedicated to SQL Server.  You will need the rest for Windows and your other applications.  On a system with a total of 2 GB RAM it is actually quite a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2008 R2 has a number of advantages over earlier versions - Standard edition allows for compressed backup - which can be restored on the R2 express version provide they are less than 10GB. (earlier versions limited to 4GB) The SQL Management studio in 2008R2 has intellisense- and as intellisense goes in SQL its quite good. 2008 R2 will still run on XP appropriately service packed. Both are solid as rocks. There are a number of (useful) extensions to the SQL language in the area of joins. There are a number of useful additons to data types (geographic and geometric) and indexes.