# Which are new features added into SQL Server 2008 over 2005?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, ssms

Main idea to put these question is get exact features of SQL Server 2008 and how can I use it in my project.

So, please help to understand or explain me about SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know what's in SQL Server 2005, might I suggest looking at Microsoft's "[What's New (SQL Server 2008)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435(v=SQL.100).aspx)".  It lists the following as being new/updated:

> - Database Engine
> - Analysis Services - Multidimensional Database
> - Analysis Services - Data Mining
> - Integration Services
> - Replication
> - Reporting Services
> - Service Broker

I don't see mention of Intellisense, but that is one new feature of SQL Server 2008 vs SQL Server 2005 that is definitely nice.

For a similar question, see: [StackOverflow: Advantages to MS SQL Server 2008 over MS SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198478/advantages-of-ms-sql-server-2008-over-ms-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1):

Activity monitor has been revamped so debugging and DB maintenance can be made easier and more reliable.

It exposes the data graphically in little graphs and in real-time, continuously updating.

I found this feature very useful in our projects.