# Difference of Commands between SQL Server 2005 and 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have looked through many pages trying to find this information but all I get is the backbone structure and how the SQL server runs. What I would like to know is the difference of commands. Which commands can you use in 2008 but are not supported in 2005 with or without adjusting the compatibility level. I design different queries and my clients differ in their database versions. So when I create something, I would like to know if it will work before I put the time in or start actually breaking my head over why the code doesn't work on the clients computer but it does on mine. An example would be Pivot where I have to change the compatibility.

So what commands have changed? Either a link to a page or if it's not much to type out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721270%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) has a list of the new commands in SQL 2008 T-SQL

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for. I will mark it when I can.

Answer (score 0):

There is some info here but it's not a whole lot so I am suspect that it's complete listing

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Version control!

*Usually* lower version's commands are available and work well in higher versions. But not quite the other way around. Take a look at the following post.

- [Advantages of SQL Server 2008 over SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198478/advantages-of-sql-server-2008-over-sql-server-2005)

For each major version [Microsoft does release improvements done or changes made under product info.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/product-info/overview-capabilities.aspx)

Comment: That site lists more the backbone, behind the scene differences. I just needed to know the actual coding that is different.

Comment: @JohnZ the backbone actually makes more of the differences in terms for a database - specially as you are looking for performance. In general how much SQL Commands can change? :) Anyway, you have chosen an answer, in the mean time, Can you give us an example of a scenario that you faced in `coding` perspective?